# How to make while loop stop if it's <= 0

Tags: c++

So I'm new to coding and I'm doing this for a class project. How do I make it where the `while` loop stops if it's <= to 0. If I put <= to 0 it doesn't do the loop at all and if I put it !=
it works, but it sometimes goes negative resulting in the loop never stopping. Is there something I'm missing? I have no idea why <= 0 wouldn't work

```
int main()
{
    
    while (health != 0 && enemy_health != 0) {

        std::cout << "Player    " "   Health: " << health << " Level: " << level << "\n";
        std::cout << "Inventory    " << "Gold:   " << gold << "   Keys:  " << keys << " Health Potions: " << health_potions << "\n\n";
        std::cout << "Fist: " << fist_damage << " damage " << " Torch: " << torch_damage << " damage \n" << "                Status Effects:\n\n" <<"                Burn:  " << burn_damage << " damage\n\n";

        std::cout << "Use: ";
        std::cin >> input;

        if (input == Fist) {

            std::cout << "\nYou did " << fist_damage << " damage\n\n";
            std::cout << "Monsters Health: " << enemy_health << "\n";
            playerAttack = true;

        }
        else if (input == Torch) {

            std::cout << "\nYou did " << torch_damage << " damage\n" << "You did " << burn_damage << " burn damage\n\n";
            int total = enemy_health - (torch_damage + burn_damage);
            enemy_health = total;
            std::cout << "Monsters Health: " << enemy_health;
            torch_durability--;
            playerAttack = true;
            isBurning = true;

        }

        while (playerAttack != true) {

            std::cout << "\n\nPlease enter a valid answer\n\n";
            std::cout << "Use: ";
            std::cin >> input;

            if (input == Fist) {

                std::cout << "\nYou did " << fist_damage << " damage\n\n";
                std::cout << "Monsters Health: " << enemy_health << "\n";
                playerAttack = true;

            }
            else if (input == Torch) {

                std::cout << "\nYou did " << torch_damage << " damage\n" << "You did " << burn_damage << " burn damage\n\n";
                int total = enemy_health - (torch_damage + burn_damage);
                enemy_health = total;
                std::cout << "Monsters Health: " << enemy_health;
                torch_durability--;
                playerAttack = true;
                isBurning = true;

            }

        }
        
        if (playerAttack == true) {

            std::cout << "\n\nThe enemy attacks\n\n";

        }

        if (dodge_chance == 5) {

            std::cout << "\n\nYou dodged the enemies attack\n\n";

        }
        else if (dodge_chance != 5) {

            std::cout << "The enemy landing a crushing blow\n\n";
            playerHit = enemy1_damage;
            int health_real = health - playerHit;
            health = health_real;
            std::cout << "The enemy does " << playerHit << " damage\n\n";

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `while (health > 0 && enemy_health > 0)` will loop until one or both healths have reached 0 or become negative.

Comment: Way too much code for such a straightforward question. Don't expect people to wade through all that stuff to figure out what you're asking.

Comment: "How do I make it where the while loop stops if it's <= to 0" - `while (whatever > 0) { ...` ...

Answer (score 7):

When asking questions or just for debugging, it is a good idea to **isolate the part that is giving you trouble**. Most of the code you have posted is irrelevant and makes it harder to read and test.

From what I understand, you have tried putting

```cpp
while (health <= 0 && enemy_health <= 0)
```

instead of your current loop ?

If so, then it is simply a logic error. You are asking the code to loop `while player health is negative or zero`. Simply changing to

```cpp
while (health > 0 && enemy_health > 0)
```

would work.